# Svnkit Resolve a tree conflict

Tags: java, svn

I am using `SvnKit` in my application to manage my working copy and the repository. I am facing following issue: I have a file that was edited in the working copy and deleted on the repository. When I am trying to commit, I see that this file is in conflict, but I don't know how to solve it.

For those who use `SvnKit`, I tried to resolve the conflict by using:

```
doResolve(java.io.File path, SVNDepth depth, boolean resolveContents, boolean resolveProperties, boolean resolveTree, SVNConflictChoice conflictChoice)
```

I set the conflict choice to  `SVNConflictChoice.MINE_FULL`  and `SVNDepth.EMPTY`, but that doesn't work.

Do anyone have an idea?

This is a part of the code I use

First, on my file, I perform a update operation by doing this

```
 ourClientManager.getUpdateClient().doUpdate(new File[]{file}),SVNRevision.HEAD,SVNDepth.EMPTY, true, false);
```

in order to set the conflict, and to resolve it. Then I check if the status of the file changed :

```
SVNStatus status = null;
try {
 status = ourClientManager.getStatusClient().doStatus(file, false);
} catch (SVNException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
if (status != null) {
       SVNConflictChoice conflictChoice = null;
       if (status.isConflicted()) {
             if (localIsRight) {
                   conflictChoice = SVNConflictChoice.MINE_FULL;
                }
             else {
                   conflictChoice = SVNConflictChoice.THEIRS_FULL;
                }
         try {
              ourClientManager.getWCClient().doResolve(file, SVNDepth.EMPTY,
               true, true, true, conflictChoice);
         } catch (SVNException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
           }
       } 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some of the code you're using?  My guess just from your question is that you're giving the path to the working copy and not the file and since the depth is `SVNDepth.EMPTY` it only tries to resolve the working copy directory rather than the file.  But there's simply not enough info here for anyone to really help you.

Comment: I edited the question with extra code

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. If you think SVNKit works incorrectly, report this to svnkit-users@svnkit.com . Please also specify in the letter, what SVNKit version you're using and include a reproducing test (containing conflict generation and resolution).